# Why TypeScirpt class property undefined

Tags: typescript, undefined

I have following code:-

```
class FeedbackController {

  public homePage(req, res){
    this.test();
    res.send('Welcome to feedback service');
  }
 
  private test(){
    console.log('test called');
  }
}

export default new FeedbackController();
```

This is how it is called:-

```
import FeedbackController from '../controller/feedbackController';

    const routes = (app) => {
        app.route('/')
        .get(FeedbackController.homePage);

    };

    export default routes;
```

I get error :-

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined

What is wrong

Comment: How is `homePage` called?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Try adding a default constructor

Comment: I added more code. Hopefully, it is clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a TS problem, check how `this` works in JS [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

As a solution replace routes with

```
.get((req, res) => FeedbackController.homePage(req, res))
```

or

```
.get(FeedbackController.homePage.bind(FeedbackController))
```

Comment: added missing arguments